# failproof way of converting an implicit equation of a line to a parametric one

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I think I am overlooking the obvious but still, what am I overlooking?

Suppose I have an line $ Ax +By + C = 0 $

And I want to rewrite it to:

$ x = D(t) + E $ and $ y = F(t) + G $

With the snag that A or B (but not both) can be $0$, also other values can be zero ( so dividing by anything just not possible)

I just failed to do it (without the snag it is easy)

or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the *standard form* $Ax+By=C$ into *normal form* by dividing both sides by $\sqrt {A^2+B^2}$. You can do this since not both $A$ and $B$ are zero. You then get

$$ax+by=r$$

where $a^2+b^2=1$. Then a point on the line, in fact the point that is closest to the origin, is $(ar, br)$. If you substitute this point into the normal form equation, you get

$$a \cdot ar + b \cdot br = (a^2+b^2) \cdot r = 1 \cdot r = r$$

So you can use these parametric equations, which have the advantage that changing $t$ by $1$ also changes the *distance* of $(x,y)$ by $1$:

$$x(t) = ar + bt$$
$$y(t) = br - at$$

If you really want to use the original $A$, $B$, and $C$, and lose the distance property above, you could use

$$x(t) = {AC \over A^2+B^2} + Bt$$
$$y(t) = {BC \over A^2+B^2} - At$$

Note that $C$ in my equations is not exactly the same as your $C$.

Answer (score 1):

Pick any point $(x_0, y_0)$ on the line. Since the (nonzero) vector $(-B, A)$ is parallel to the line, we can parametrize the line by

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
    x(t) := x_0 - B t \\
    y(t) := y_0 + A t
\end{array}
\right.\textrm{.}$$

Comment: will do for me, but what if you cannot find a point $(x_0, y_0) $

Comment: You can always do this quickly. If $A \neq 0$, then $(-\frac{C}{A}, 0)$ is on the line. If $A = 0$, then the line is just $y = -\frac{C}{B}$, so you can take the point $(x_0, -\frac{C}{B})$ for any $x_0$.

Comment: the problem is a bit that in advance you don't know which of A or B is zero (if one is zero)

Comment: In that case, you can simply determine the point which is closest to the origin (there always is one), and Rory has conveniently already done so in his excellent answer.